# How to know which column flagged up in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Here's a tricky one (I think...)

Let say I have four columns : SKU, UPC, Product_Description and Product_ID

I have this kind of query:

```
SELECT UPC, SKU, Product_Description, Product_ID
FROM tblProducts 
WHERE UPC LIKE '%$q%' OR SKU LIKE '%$q%' OR Product_Description LIKE '%$q%'
```

I need all information to be retrieved (product_ID, SKU, UPC and so on...) and must importantly, I must know which column fitted the LIKE (is it UPC or SKU or Product_Description???)

I was thinking about making the ~ same query 3 times (one for the SKU, another one for the UPC, etc) to know which one fitted the like. But I guess there's a better way to do that.

Comment: So `$q` is a variable for the search term, correct? I'm curious about your data.. since you look up for a single `$q` variable, does that mean all `SKU`, `UPC` and `Product_Description` might store similar type of records? I mean it's possible but usually these product information differ. For example, in some cases `SKU` or `UPC` might be just number and `Product_Description` is usually the text description of the product, right?

Comment: You're correct, $q is my search term. It's not the same kind of data. UPC is numbers only. SKU it depends. Product_Description is alphanumeric.

Comment: I suggest you provide some sample data and expected output. Here, you can use this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c3c2ba8155592d6f02c1d1d422054e2b . Edit it as you wish then click "Run". After that it will generate a new link and you can post that [into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70104162/edit)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT UPC, SKU, Product_Description, Product_ID, 'UPC' AS `Matching_Column`
FROM tblProducts WHERE UPC LIKE '%$q%' 
UNION
SELECT UPC, SKU, Product_Description, Product_ID, 'SKU'
FROM tblProducts WHERE SKU LIKE '%$q%' 
UNION
SELECT UPC, SKU, Product_Description, Product_ID, 'Product_Description'
FROM tblProducts WHERE Product_Description LIKE '%$q%'
```

Although the above solution has a chance of repeating rows, if the match is found in more than one column.

Here's another possible solution:

```
SELECT UPC, SKU, Product_Description, Product_ID, 
  (UPC LIKE '%$q%') AS `UPC_Matches`,
  (SKU LIKE '%$q%') AS `SKU_Matches`,
  (Product_Description LIKE '%$q%') AS `Product_Description_Matches`
FROM tblProducts WHERE UPC LIKE '%$q%' 
  OR SKU LIKE '%$q%' 
  OR Product_Description LIKE '%$q%'
```

Comment: For the first option, wouldn't UNION ALL be slightly more efficient?

Comment: Efficiency is apparently not a concern, since the OP's query uses wildcards in LIKE patterns.